# Writing Woocommerce product data to downloadable CSV

Tags: csv, woocommerce

I'm trying to write the product details from a woocommerce product page to a downloadable CSV, on the click of a button.

Similar structure to this:

```
<?php
            
            $header_args = array( 'SKU', 'Description', 'Price' );
            header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=csv_export.csv');
            $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
            ob_end_clean();
            fputcsv($output, $header_args);
            
            $data = array(
                '0' => array( '$product->get_sku();', '$product->get_description();', '$product->get_price();' ),
            );
            
            foreach($data AS $data_item){
                fputcsv($output, $data_item);
            }
            exit;
            ?>
```

Can someone assist on how I can alter this code? so on a button click or link click, a CSV will download with SKU, Description & Price?

Comment: Try this [WooCommerce product export free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Comment: hey - thanks for the suggestion. I already have that plugin installed for backend.

what i'm trying to achieve is a button on the 'front end' ie product page, which they click and it exports the product data for that specific product, to a csv or pdf which is then downloadable.